# accessing dictionary from a Json string in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a JSON string as a response from server which contains key value pairs like dictionary. Some of the keys can have dictionary as their values as well. I have to access values based on certain keys from the inner dictionary. How can i access them and store in a string?

Something like this:-

```
string JsonData = "{\"status\":\"BAD_REQUEST\",\"code\":400,\"errorsCount\":1,\"errors\":[{\"desciption\":\"Field cannot be blank\"}]}";

string toBeAccessedValue = Field cannot be blank;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[JsonExtensionData]` to deserialize your json to class object.

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> data { get; set; }
}
```

And you can use above class like

```
RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JsonData);

var errors = ro.data["errors"].ToObject<JObject[]>();

string description = errors.FirstOrDefault().Property("desciption").Value?.ToString();

Console.WriteLine("description: " + description);

Console.ReadLine();
```

---

**Alternative:**

You can use below class structure that can be helpful to you to deserialize your json and retrieve any value that you want.

```
public class Error
{
    public string desciption { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public int errorsCount { get; set; }
    public List<Error> errors { get; set; }
}
```

And you can use above class structure to deserealize your json like

```
RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JsonData);

string description = rootObject.errors.FirstOrDefault()?.desciption;

Console.WriteLine("description: " + description);

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Edit:**

If you want to deserialize your json with `JavaScriptSerializer` then.

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

RootObject rootObject = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(JsonData);

string description = rootObject.errors.FirstOrDefault()?.desciption;

Console.WriteLine("description: " + description);

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks er-shoaib. But is there any way we can use JavaScriptSerializer to achieve the same?

Comment: @AakashGoutam, answer updated. kindly view **Edit** section in answer. If answer was helpful to you then mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)

Comment: Thanks, i somehow managed to get hold of the right answer. But i do appreciate your help and time.